# Displaying data in textview through json

Tags: android, json, textview

I want to display user details from mysql database through php and display it in android textview. The scenario is like this: When the user logged in to his account he will be redirected to  the dashboard which contains of 4 buttons namely: newsfeed, profile, calendar and about. When the user clicks the profile button the user details like his lastname, firstname, middleinitial etc will be displayed in the textview. When i run my app, it doesnt display anything but in my php script it returns the user details. What seems to be the problem here?

Here is my java code:

```
package sscr.stag;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class AdProfile extends Activity {
// All xml labels

TextView txtFname;
TextView txtMname;
TextView txtLname;

// Progress Dialog
private ProgressDialog pDialog;

// Creating JSON Parser object
JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

// Profile json object
JSONArray user;
JSONObject hay;
// Profile JSON url
private static final String PROFILE_URL     ="http://www.stagconnect.com/StagConnect/admin/TestProfile.php";

// ALL JSON node names
private static final String TAG_PROFILE = "user";
// private static final String TAG_ID = "id";
private static final String TAG_USERNAME = "username";
private static final String TAG_FIRSTNAME = "first_name";
private static final String TAG_MIDDLENAME = "middle_initial";
private static final String TAG_LASTNAME = "last_name";


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.adminprofile);


txtFname = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.fname);
txtMname = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mname);
txtLname = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lname);

// Loading Profile in Background Thread
new LoadProfile().execute();
}

class LoadProfile extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {


public void test(){

 hay = new JSONObject();

        // Storing each json item in variable
        try {
            String firstname = hay.getString(TAG_FIRSTNAME);
            String middlename = hay.getString(TAG_MIDDLENAME);
            String lastname = hay.getString(TAG_LASTNAME);

            // displaying all data in textview

           txtFname.setText("Firstname: " + firstname);
            txtMname.setText("Middle Name: " + middlename);
            txtLname.setText("Last Name " + lastname);

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

 }

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
super.onPreExecute();
pDialog = new ProgressDialog(AdProfile.this);
pDialog.setMessage("Loading profile ...");
pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
pDialog.setCancelable(false);
pDialog.show();
}
   /**
    * getting Profile JSON
    * */
   protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
    // Building Parameters

SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(AdProfile.this);
String post_username = sp.getString("username", "anon");
List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", post_username));
// getting JSON string from URL
JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(PROFILE_URL, "POST",
        params);

// Check your log cat for JSON reponse
Log.d("Profile JSON: ", json.toString());

try {
    // profile json object
    user = json.getJSONArray(TAG_PROFILE);
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

return null;
}


protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
// dismiss the dialog after getting all products
pDialog.dismiss();
// updating UI from Background Thread
test();

}

}
}
```

And here is my php script:

```
<?php


require('admin.config.inc.php');


if (!empty($_POST)) {

    //initial query
    $query = "Select last_name, first_name, middle_initial, designation FROM admin where username = :user";

    $query_params = array(':user' => $_POST['username']);

    //execute query
    try {
        $stmt = $db -> prepare($query);
        $result = $stmt -> execute($query_params);
    } catch (PDOException $ex) {
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "Database Error!";
        die(json_encode($response));
    }

    // Finally, we can retrieve all of the found rows into an array using fetchAll 
    $rows = $stmt -> fetchAll();

    if ($rows) {
        $response["success"] = 1;
        $response["message"] = "Post Available!";
        $response["user"] = array();

        foreach($rows as $row) {
            $user = array();
            $user["designation"] = $row["designation"];
            $user["middlename"] = $row["middle_initial"];
            $user["firstname"] = $row["first_name"];
            $user["lastname"] = $row["last_name"];

            //update our repsonse JSON data
            array_push($response["user"], $user);
        }

        // echoing JSON response
        echo json_encode($response);

    } else {
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "No user available!";
        die(json_encode($response));
    }

} else {}


       ?>

 <form action="TestProfile.php" method="POST">
 Username: <input type="text" name="username">
 <input type="submit" value="Submit">
 </form>
```

Here the output of my php script(JSON Response):

```
{"success":1,"message":"Post Available!","user":[{"designation":"Student Affairs Office in charge","middlename":"","firstname":"test","lastname":"test"}]}
```

Comment: `hay = new JSONObject();` should be  `hay = new JSONObject("jsonstrin");`

Comment: I got this error: Unhandled exception type JSONException

Comment: `json` and `user` object are totally ignored. where were you supposed to display something ?

Comment: I want to display it in textview sir, im sorry i dont know what to do im just new in android

Comment: @IamAndroida Please see my answer Your problem will be definitely resolved

Comment: wheres your answer sir? @RavindMaurya

Comment: @IamAndroida http://www.stagconnect.com/StagConnect/admin/TestProfile.php. open this in a browser and type the name you want. it seems it returns nothing. i guess your username is not valid. So this means it has nothing to do with the code. After this comes your coding part

Comment: there are only two username stored in my database sir, it is just admin and mae. try it and you'l see the output

Comment: @IamAndroida i go the response. i will post it in a while

Comment: i hope u can help me again in my future questions :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the json object

```
JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(PROFILE_URL, "POST",
    params);
```

You need to return `json` in `doInbackground`. The result returned is param to `onPostExecute`

Then

```
 test(json);
```

And then in test you can parse the json

Edit:

You would also need to change

```
 AsyncTask<String, String, String>
```

to

```
AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject>
```

Then

```
protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {

JSONObject json=null;  
    // Building Parameters

SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(AdProfile.this);
String post_username = sp.getString("username", "anon");
List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", post_username));
// getting JSON string from URL
json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(PROFILE_URL, "POST",
        params);

// Check your log cat for JSON reponse
Log.d("Profile JSON: ", json.toString());

try {
    // profile json object
    user = json.getJSONArray(TAG_PROFILE);
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

return json;
}
```

Then in onPostExecute

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject result) {
super.onPOstExecute(result);
// dismiss the dialog after getting all products
pDialog.dismiss();
// updating UI from Background Thread
test(result);
}
```

In `test`

```
public void test(JSONObject response){
{
       // parse response here and set text to textview
}
```

Or

Do you parsing in `doInbackgrond` update textview in onPostExecute

Edit:

[image]

Code:

```
public class AddProfile extends Activity {
    // All xml labels

    TextView txtFname;
    TextView txtMname;
    TextView txtLname;

    // Progress Dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    // Profile json object
    JSONArray user;
    JSONObject hay;
    // Profile JSON url
    private static final String PROFILE_URL = "http://www.stagconnect.com/StagConnect/admin/TestProfile.php";

    // ALL JSON node names
    private static final String TAG_PROFILE = "user";
    // private static final String TAG_ID = "id";
    private static final String TAG_USERNAME = "username";
    private static final String TAG_FIRSTNAME = "first_name";
    private static final String TAG_MIDDLENAME = "middle_initial";
    private static final String TAG_LASTNAME = "last_name";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.adminprofile);

        txtFname = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.fname);
        txtMname = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lname);
        txtLname = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mname);

        // Loading Profile in Background Thread
        new LoadProfile().execute();
    }

    class LoadProfile extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {



        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(AddProfile.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading profile ...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        /**
         * getting Profile JSON
         * */
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
            // Building Parameters
            String json = null;
            try {
                List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", "admin"));

                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(PROFILE_URL);
                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

                // Execute HTTP Post Request
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();
                json = EntityUtils.toString(resEntity);

                Log.i("Profile JSON: ", json.toString());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return json;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String json) {
            super.onPostExecute(json);
            // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
            pDialog.dismiss();
            try
            {
            hay = new JSONObject(json);
            JSONArray user = hay.getJSONArray("user");
            JSONObject jb= user.getJSONObject(0);
            String firstname = jb.getString("firstname");
            String middlename = jb.getString("middlename");
            String lastname = jb.getString("lastname");

            // displaying all data in textview

            txtFname.setText("Firstname: " + firstname);
            txtMname.setText("Middle Name: " + middlename);
            txtLname.setText("Last Name " + lastname);
            }catch(Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

    }
}
```

The json

```
{ // json object node 
    "success": 1,
    "message": "Post Available!",
    "user": [ // json array user
        {     // json object node 
            "designation": "Student Affairs Office in-charge",
            "middlename": "",
            "firstname": "Jose Patrick",
            "lastname": "Ocampo"
        }
    ]
}
```

Browser snap shot

[image]

Comment: the method test was not complete

Comment: Can you tell me how to do that sir? Im so sorry i dont know how to do it, I'm just a beginner in android thanks a lot

Comment: @Raghu.. the parsing method was not complete .when first she posted.

Comment: @RalucaGurau what has that gotta do with my post?

Comment: @Iam please check if your permissions from maifest files are set . Also do it step by step : check if you receive the response, check if your ui componnents are not null , check if you parsed corectly

Comment: @Raghunandan nothing , sorry I thought you want to give the completed solution and you did not wrote the method for parsing , my mistake

Comment: @Raghunandan, Hi sir. it says in my logcat "No user available." Do i have to change some codes  in the doInBackground? maybe its not connected? It doesn't recognizes the usernname i logged in

Comment: @IamAndroida  i don't understand your comment.

Comment: @IamAndroida looking at the code again your test method does not have the json that you got from the server. So you need to pass the json that you get from the server to that method. That is what is actually missing your code

Comment: I want to get the user details(eg. first name, last name etc) from the user who logged in to the app. The user details is stored in mysql database. It returns "No user available" in my logcat. I dont understand whats the problem here sir im sorry

Comment: It doesnt display anything in the textview, it remains blank

Comment: @IamAndroida i am sorry i can't help furhter if you can't follow the suggestion. good luck. if there is nothing to display it will be blank

Comment: @IamAndroida give me some time i will post a complete answer beyound which i can't help further

Comment: Thanks so much sir. I look forward to it.

Answer (score 1):

First of all the method that will do the parsing should have a parameter with the string

Let s say parseFromPhp (String response)

Your json object also contain an inner Json Object that is "user":[{"designation":"Student Affairs Office in- charge","middlename":"","firstname":"test","lastname":"test"}]}

For parse this you will do

```
        JSONObject jsonRespone = new JSONObject(response); 
        JSONObject user= jsonRespone.getJSONObject("user");
        String lastName  = user.optString ("lastName");
```

If you want to get the message you will  do like this :

```
        String message= jsonResponse.optString ("message");
```

Comment: Am i going to put that parsing in the doInBackground?

Comment: Yes in do in background you do : get string from server , call parse method with the message received

Comment: try {
       
        user = json.getJSONArray(TAG_PROFILE); // i get error here sir, it says:Type mismatch: cannot convert from JSONArray to JSONObject 
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;

Answer (score 0):

DO THIS In 
**doInBackground()** method

```
try {
       // profile json object
       user = json.getJSONArray(TAG_PROFILE);
       for (int i = 0; i < user.length(); i++)
       {
         JSONObject FObject = json.getJSONObject(i);

          hay = FObject.getJSONObject("user");
        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
     }
```

And then remove this in **test()**

```
hay = new JSONObject();
```

Comment: she should have a method to call, for example  parseREsponse ().. to be more clean ...otherwise doInBackground will have a lot of lines and be hard to read

Comment: The method getJSONObject(String) in the type JSONObject is not applicable for the arguments (int)

It is an error in line of JSONObject FObject = json.getJSONObject(i);