# How can I display data from MySQL to Android TextView using my logged in username?

Tags: php, android, mysql, json, textview

I am trying to develop an Android app using php,json, and mysql. I want to get user details using logged in username of a certain user. The scenario is a user logged in and directed to his dashboard contains four buttons: one button for his profile and if clicked he will viewed his personal info. I have similar problem with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21093869/displaying-data-in-textview-through-json)... but I encountered several errors which quiet bad I can't do with my own. I am new to Android. Please anyone with great heart can help me.....???!!

**This is my java code:**

```
 package com.myapp;

 import java.util.ArrayList;
 import java.util.List;

 import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
 import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
 import org.json.JSONArray;
 import org.json.JSONException;
 import org.json.JSONObject;

 import library.JSONParser;
 import library.UserLogout;
 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.app.ProgressDialog;
 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.content.SharedPreferences;
 import android.os.AsyncTask;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
 import android.util.Log;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
 import android.widget.Button;
 import android.widget.TextView;

public class ProfileView extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
private Button bBack, bLogout;
private TextView tvusername, tvfullname;

// Progress Dialog
private ProgressDialog pDialog;

// Creating JSON Parser object
JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

// Profile json object
JSONArray user;
JSONObject display;

// Profile JSON url
private static final String PROFILE_URL = "http://10.0.2.2/webservice/profile.php";

// ALL JSON node names
private static final String TAG_PROFILE = "user";
// private static final String TAG_ID = "id";
private static final String TAG_USERNAME = "username";
private static final String TAG_FULLNAME = "fullname";




@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.profile);

    //setup textview
    tvusername=(TextView)(findViewById(R.id.tvusernamedisplay));
    tvfullname=(TextView)(findViewById(R.id.tvfullname));


    //settup buttons
    bBack=(Button)(findViewById(R.id.bBack));
    bLogout=(Button)(findViewById(R.id.blogout));

    //button listener
    bBack.setOnClickListener(this);
    bLogout.setOnClickListener(this);

    // Loading Profile in Background Thread
    new LoadProfile().execute();

}

@Override
public void onClick(View args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (args.getId()) {
    case R.id.bBack:
    Intent b = new Intent(this, Dashboard.class);
    startActivity(b);
    break;
    case R.id.blogout:
    Intent out = new Intent(this, UserLogout.class);
    startActivity(out);
    default:
    break;
    }
}

class LoadProfile extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject> {


    public void test(JSONObject response){

     display = new JSONObject();

            // Storing each json item in variable
            try {
                String idnum = display.getString(TAG_USERNAME);
                String full = display.getString(TAG_FULLNAME);


                // displaying all data in textview

               tvusername.setText(idnum);
                tvfullname.setText(full);


            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

     }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(ProfileView.this);
    pDialog.setMessage("Loading Profile ...");
    pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
    pDialog.setCancelable(false);
    pDialog.show();
    }
       /**
        * getting Profile JSON
        * */
       protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... args) {
        // Building Parameters

           JSONObject json=null;  
            // Building Parameters

        SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ProfileView.this);
        String post_username = sp.getString("username", "anon");
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", post_username));
        // getting JSON string from URL
        json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(PROFILE_URL, "POST", params);

        // Check your log cat for JSON reponse
        Log.d("Profile JSON: ", json.toString());

        try {
            // profile json object
            user = json.getJSONArray(TAG_PROFILE);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return json;
        }


       protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject result) {
           super.onPostExecute(result);
           // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
           pDialog.dismiss();
           // updating UI from Background Thread
           test(result);
           }

      }
   }
```

**This is my PHP script:**

```
<?php

/*
Our "config.php" file connects to database every time we include or require
it within a php script.  Since we want this script to query data from a user logged in to our db,
we will be talking with our database, and therefore,
let's require the connection to happen:
*/
require("config.php");

if (!empty($_POST)) {
    //gets user's info based off of a username.
    $query = "
            SELECT
                username,
                CONCAT(lastname, ',' , firstname, ' ' , middlename) as lastname
            FROM user
            WHERE
                username = :username
        ";
 //COUNT(ftload) as ftload,
    $query_params = array(
        ':username' => $_POST['username']
    );

    try {
        $stmt   = $db->prepare($query);
        $result = $stmt->execute($query_params);
}
catch (PDOException $ex) {
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Database Error!";
    die(json_encode($response));
}

// Finally, we can retrieve all of the found rows into an array using fetchAll
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll();


if ($rows) {
    $response["success"] = 1;
    $response["message"] = "User Profile!";
    $response["user"]   = array();

    foreach ($rows as $row) {
        $user             = array();

        //this line is new:
      //$post["post_id"]  = $row["post_id"];

        $user ["username"] = $row["username"];

       $user ["lastname"]  = $row["lastname"];



        //update our repsonse JSON data
        array_push($response["user"], $user );
    }

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);


} else {
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "No Post Available!";
    die(json_encode($response));
}
}
?>
 <form action="testprofile.php" method="POST">
 Username: <input type="text" name="username">
 <input type="submit" value="Submit">
 </form>
```

**This is my json response from my testprofile above:**

```
{"success":1,"message":"User Profile!","user":    [{"username":"10094","lastname":"MARTINEZ,Pot Pama"}]}
```

**This is my logcat error:**

```
08-09 18:35:46.373: I/ActivityManager(291): Displayed 

com.myapp/.ProfileView: +3s247ms
08-09 18:35:49.173: D/Profile JSON:(841): {"message":"User 

Profile!","user":[{"lastname":"MARTINEZ,Pot 

Pama","username":"10094"}],"success":1}
08-09 18:35:49.213: W/System.err(841): org.json.JSONException: No value for 

username
08-09 18:35:49.233: W/System.err(841):  at org.json.JSONObject.get

(JSONObject.java:354)
08-09 18:35:49.233: W/System.err(841):  at org.json.JSONObject.getString

(JSONObject.java:510)
08-09 18:35:49.243: W/System.err(841):  at com.sjpmingfinal.ProfileView

$LoadProfile.test(ProfileView.java:102)
08-09 18:35:49.243: W/System.err(841):  at com.sjpmingfinal.ProfileView

$LoadProfile.onPostExecute(ProfileView.java:164)
08-09 18:35:49.243: W/System.err(841):  at com.sjpmingfinal.ProfileView

$LoadProfile.onPostExecute(ProfileView.java:1)
08-09 18:35:49.243: W/System.err(841):  at android.os.AsyncTask.finish

(AsyncTask.java:631)
08-09 18:35:49.243: W/System.err(841):  at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600

(AsyncTask.java:177)
08-09 18:35:49.253: W/System.err(841):  at android.os.AsyncTask

$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:644)
08-09 18:35:49.253: W/System.err(841):  at 

android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-09 18:35:49.253: W/System.err(841):  at android.os.Looper.loop

(Looper.java:137)
08-09 18:35:49.263: W/System.err(841):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main

(ActivityThread.java:5041)
08-09 18:35:49.263: W/System.err(841):  at 

java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-09 18:35:49.263: W/System.err(841):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke

(Method.java:511)
08-09 18:35:49.263: W/System.err(841):  at 

com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run

(ZygoteInit.java:793)
08-09 18:35:49.283: W/System.err(841):  at 

com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
08-09 18:35:49.293: W/System.err(841):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main

(Native Method)
: E/(): Device disconnected: 1
: E/(): Device disconnected
```

**Edit: I solved it on my own.
See my answer guys below.....**

Comment: can u post json response?

Comment: @adcom: this is my json response in php {"success":1,"message":"User Profile!","user":[{"username":"10094","lastname":"MARTINEZ,Pot Pama"}]}

Comment: did that webservice return reposnse in ur logcat? did u used online json parser to see if json is valid or not

Comment: json is valid @adcom , this is my logcat response com.myapp/.ProfileView: +3s247ms
08-09 18:35:49.173: D/Profile JSON:(841): {"message":"User 

Profile!","user":[{"lastname":"MARTINEZ,Pot 

Pama","username":"10094"}],"success":1}
08-09 18:35:49.213: W/System.err(841): org.json.JSONException: No value for 

username but the problem after the response in logcat it says on my logcat: 08-09 18:35:49.213: W/System.err(841): org.json.JSONException: No value for 

username

Answer (score 1):

**Yey! I solve it on my own. Cheers!**
I made changes in my posted codes. please bear with it, i may not be a good programmer but to those slow beginners like me don't throw away yourself, always use **trial and error** method hehe and gave attention to people here who gave hints and advise...

I made a few lines of code on my **Login** java:
Do it in my doinbackground using sharedprefs

```
 // save user data
    SharedPreferences prefs =   PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    editor.putString("username", username);
    editor.commit();
Intent i = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, ProfileView.class);
    // this is where you should pass the username
    i.putExtra("username", username);
    //finish();
    startActivity(i);
    finish();
.......
```

And on my **Profile** java:
use and add this code in onCreate to get your extras from your login java where your sharedpref is

```
Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras.containsKey("username")) {
        ngalan = extras.getString("username");
     // Loading Profile in Background Thread
        new LoadProfile().execute();
    }
```

and finally use this inside your asynctask class in getting json profile:

```
 /**
     * getting Profile JSON
     * */
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        // Building Parameters
        String json=null;


        try {
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", ngalan));

            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(PROFILE_URL);
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

            // Execute HTTP Post Request
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();
            json = EntityUtils.toString(resEntity);

            Log.i("Profile JSON: ", json.toString());

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        return json;
    }
```

I know there are shorter or quickest or smartest way to get data and displays on textview however happy to know my code is doing good. Hope it helps you too.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, first of all i think you are calling wrong your attribute from JSON. 
Instead of using:

```
try {
        // profile json object
        user = json.getJSONArray(TAG_PROFILE);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Try with this:

```
try {
    String username= (String) json.get(TAG_PROFILE);
}catch...
```

Comment: it says the "username" of your code String username is not used, how to use it after?

Comment: I run your code but I have errors pls see my logcat I dont know whats going on it says myapp has stopped:08-10 08:33:36.690: E/WindowManager(891): Activity com.myapp.ProfileView has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{40fd1c38 V.E..... R.....ID 0,0-324,175} that was originally added here

Comment: The "Leaked Window" error happens when there is something wrong with your dialog window. Check how you are adding the progress dialog or updating your UI when the asynk task is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Why you don´t try this, in your php put

```
<?php
    $dato = $_POST["data"];
    $id = $dato["id"];
    $DB_HostName = "host_name";
    $DB_Name = "db_name";
    $DB_User = "user_name";
    $DB_Pass = "your_password";
    $DB_Table = "table";
    $con = mysql_connect($DB_HostName,$DB_User,$DB_Pass) or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db($DB_Name,$con) or die(mysql_error()); 
    $sql = "SELECT column1, column2, etc FROM $DB_Table WHERE id = '$id';";
    $res = mysql_query($sql,$con) or die(mysql_error());
    $n_filas = mysql_num_rows ($res);
    $array = array();
    for ($i=0; $i<$n_filas; $i++){
        $fila = mysql_fetch_array($res);
        $array[$i]['column1'] = $fila['column1'];
        $array[$i]['column2'] = utf8_encode($fila['column2']);
        $array[$i]['etc'] = utf8_encode($fila['etc']);
    }
    $result= json_encode($array);
    echo $result;
    return $result;
?>
```

And in your Android code:

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(http + "update_place/missing_places.php");
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
try{
   List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
   nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("data[id]", "" + id));
   httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
   HttpResponse respuesta = httpclient.execute(httppost);
   StatusLine estado = respuesta.getStatusLine();
   int codigoEstado = estado.getStatusCode();
   if (codigoEstado == 200){
      HttpEntity entidad = respuesta.getEntity();
      InputStream contenido = entidad.getContent();
      BufferedReader lector = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(contenido));
      String line;
      while ((line = lector.readLine()) != null)    builder.append(line);
      Log.e("Response", builder.toString()); //Here you can see if you've received a JSOON string
      JSONArray jsonarray = new JSONArray(builder.toString());
      for (int i=0; i<jsonarray.length(); i++){
         JSONObject jsonobj = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
         Log.e("JSONObj", "column1 = " + jsonobj.getString("column1"));
         Log.e("JSONObj", "column2 = " + jsonobj.getString("column2"));
         Log.e("JSONObj", "etc = " + jsonobj.getString("etc"));
      }
   }
   else error = true;
}
catch(HttpHostConnectException e){  error = true;   }
catch (ClientProtocolException e){  error = true;   }
catch (IOException e){  error = true;   }
```

Put attention that I use **Log.e** because is more easy find them.

Comment: I have my login php file and it logged in successfully but my problem also is the username use in my logged in php file will be use in my testprofile php above but I dont know how to do it instead I add little code to input username to check the details,can u pls help me?